# Capturing a keystroke in C++

Tags: c++, input, capture, keystrokes

I have been doing some reading, and I see that I can use getch() to get a keystroke.  What I have seen is that this is considered bad practice, however I have seen conflicting opinions.  I am writing a console application for my class, and would like to be able to move a marker(*) around the screen based on the arrow keys being pressed.  Is getch() the right way to go about this, or is there a better method to capture it.  I want them to just be able to push the arrow, not need to push enter or anything.  I don't need the code specifically, I just want to know if I should avoid getch(), and if so, what functions are there for this type of idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getch()` is not a standard function in either C or C++. It's found in some obsolete compilers, such as [Turbo C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C) and it's also defined in certain commonly used libraries such as [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29), but in any case it's a C function, not C++. For C++ you should probably just stick with standard C++ I/O. If you can't do this for some reason then go for the most portable option, e.g. curses.

Comment: is there s c++ standard way to capture keystrokes as they are typed, or does c++ always need the input to be buffered?

Comment: @bear: no there is no such way in standard c++

Comment: I think any solution is either going to be OS-specific, or is going to require a library such as curses or ncurses.

Answer (score 1):

You want to read from the terminal in non-canonical mode. Use tcsetattr() to turn off the ICANON flag.

Answer (score 0):

Use getch() if it works. Why not?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can use pdcurses: http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/, that is compatible with ncurses.