# Handling non-input keystrokes?

Tags: c++, c, input, terminate, keystrokes

I'm not sure exactly how to phrase what I'm trying to ask; in C++, using the stdio.h header instead of iostream, how would I make it so that if the escape key is pressed at any point, the program is terminated? Is there something I could add once at the top of the program, or would I have to add it to every loop/conditional individually? Below is my code (the sleep() function is just for a visual loading/calculating effect):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>

void repeat();
void quadratic()
{
    double a, b, c;
    double ans[2];
    printf("-Arrange your equation in the form aX^2+bX+c \n-Enter the value of a: ");
    scanf("%lf", &a);
    printf("-Enter the value of b: ");
    scanf("%lf", &b);
    printf("-Enter the value of c: ");
    scanf("%lf", &c);
    double radical=((b*b)-(4*a*c));
    double root=sqrt(radical);
    double negB=(-1)*b;
    double denominator=2*a;
    if(denominator==0)
    {
        printf("Calculating");
        Sleep(100);
        printf(".");
        Sleep(100);
        printf(".");
        Sleep(100);
        printf(".");
        Sleep(100);
        printf("\nError: Denominator must be non-zero.\n \n \n");

    }
    else if(radical==0)
    {
        ans[0]=negB/denominator;
        printf("Both roots are equal: both values are X=%lf\n \n \n", ans[0]);

    }
    else if(radical<0)
    {
        printf("Calculating");
        Sleep(100);
        printf(".");
        Sleep(100);
        printf(".");
        Sleep(100);
        printf(".");
        Sleep(100);
        double r,i;
        radical*=-1;
        r=negB/(2*a);
        i=sqrt(radical)/(2*a);
        printf("\nBoth roots are imaginary numbers.\n");
        printf("Non-real answer(s): X=%lf+%lfi X=%lf-%lfi\n \n \n",r,i,r,i);

    }
    else
    {
    ans[0]=(negB+root)/denominator;
    ans[1]=(negB-root)/denominator;
    printf("Calculating");
        Sleep(100);
        printf(".");
        Sleep(100);
        printf(".");
        Sleep(100);
        printf(".");
        Sleep(100);
        printf("\nX=%lf, X=%lf\n \n", ans[0], ans[1]);
    }
    repeat();

}
void repeat()
{
    quadratic();
}
int main(void)
{   
    quadratic();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `Ctrl+C` instead of `esc`?

Comment: Check the value returned by `scanf` and exit if it's less than expected.

Comment: @AustinMullins: `scanf` will pause for input.

Comment: @musiphil Good point, but if the user wants to quit, they could just hit enter with no input, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capturing a keystroke in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219506/capturing-a-keystroke-in-c)

Comment: Have you looked at ***[GetAsyncKeyState()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*** ?

Comment: @AustinMullins: Yes. But I'm guessing what the OP wanted is probably letting the program continue without interruption unless Esc is pressed.

Comment: FYI, the whole `repeat` function here could be replaced with a recursive call to `quadratic`, or better yet, throw the whole thing in a `while(1) or for(;;)` loop.  If your compiler is incapable of converting tail recursion to a loop, this will blow up the call stack eventually.

Comment: GetAsyncKeyState() does exactly that.  Run it in a while loop, or in a separate thread, and use it in conjunction with a `switch()`, to handle many different key/response response scenarios.  ***[one simple example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23064255/645128)***

Comment: How would I get GetAsyncKeyState() to run continuously without interrupting the rest of my code?

Comment: _How would I get GetAsyncKeyState() to run continuously..._?  See edits to my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

*Is there something I could add once at the top of the program, or would I have to add it to every loop/conditional individually?*

I think you can add something once, and use it to catch key stroke events easily throughout your program.

Following is a code snippet showing a function I have used to handle key stroke events in a console application.  It uses `GetAsyncKeyState()`.  Included is a section that shows how to capture a CTRL key, and how you can *do something* once you see it.  (the snippet shown shows how I capture a `<ctrl><shift><h>` key sequence to display a help menu for using this particular routine.

***Note:***  In the description, `delay_x(float delay)` is simply a custom, non-blocking sleep, or delay function that includes a call to the following snippet.  It is called from within the main program loop `while(1){...}` .  Exiting the program is provided in one of the keystroke combinations: `<CTRL><SHIFT><K>`

***Code snippet:***

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  SetAppState() is called continuously from within delay_x()
//  to capture keystroke combinations as they occur asynchronously
//  with this application, Keystroke combinations are listed below
//
//  Note: GetAsyncKeyState() can maintian information regarding the 
//        state of a key instantaineously by use the MSB, 
//        and recently by using the LSB.  
//        
//        For this application
//        only instantaineous information will be kept, minimizing
//        conflicts with other keyboard shortcut definitions 
//        defined by other applications that may be running
//        simultaineously.
//  
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void SetAppState(void)
{
    short state=0;
    short state1=0;

    state = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_CONTROL);
    if (0x80000000 & state) //check instantaineous state of key
    {
        state = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT); 
        if (0x80000000 & state) //check instantaineous state of key
        {
            state = GetAsyncKeyState('h'); 
            state1 = GetAsyncKeyState('H'); 
            if ((0x80000000 & state) || 
                (0x80000000 & state1))
            {    sprintf(gTempBuf, "Usage - keystrokes to access and control the PaAutoStartSlot application:\n\n"
                                   "<CTRL><SHIFT> H   (H)elp -    \n"
                                   "<CTRL><SHIFT> V  o(V)erride - \n"
                                   "<CTRL><SHIFT> S   (S)tatus -  \n"
                                   "<CTRL><SHIFT> K   (K)ill -    \n"
                                   "<CTRL><SHIFT> N   (N)o -      \n"
                                   "<CTRL><SHIFT> I   (I)Inside - \n"
                                   "<CTRL><SHIFT> O   (O)Outside- \n"
                                   "\nSee log file at this location for runtime errors: \n\n%s", LOGFILE); 
                 MessagePopup("Usage Menu",gTempBuf);
            }

///// ... more code ...
End of snippet
```

***Edit*** - Answer to questions in comments *how to call GetAsyncKeyState()*

There are many ways you could call `GetAsyncKeyState()` at the same time *other* stuff is going on.  Threads are a good way.  You can also do it all in line using a `while()/switch(){}` combination.  Here is a very simple example of how you could do this (in pseudo code)

```
int gRunning = 1;
int state = 1; 

int main(void)
{

    //create variables, initialize stuff
    while(gRunning)//this is your main program loop
    {
        delay_x(1.0);//check for keystrokes
        switch(state)  {
            case 1:
                //do some stuff here  
                //and experiment with values passed to delay_x(n)
                delay_x(10000);//check for keystrokes
                state++;
                break;
            case 2:
                //do some different stuff here
                delay_x(10000);//check for keystrokes
                state++;
                break;
            ... Add as many cases as you need for your program.
            case n://last case, set execution flow to top
                //do some more different stuff here
                delay_x(10000);//check for keystrokes
                state = 1;//loop back to top
                break;
         }
     }
    return 0;
}
void delay_x (float delay)
{   
    static clock_t time1;   
    static clock_t time2;   clock();    

    time1 = clock();    
    time2 = clock();    

    while ((time2 - time1) < delay) 
    {       
        time2 = clock();        
        SetAppState(); //see partial definition in my original answer above.
    }       
}
```

***Note:***  Using this method, you can have as many, or as few, `cases` as you need, the important thing is to keep a steady flow of calls to `GetAsyncKeyState()`.  This does that via the call to `delay_x()`.

***Note2:***  Here is the segment (added to above definition) that will cause your program to exit:

```
    state = GetAsyncKeyState('k'); 
    state1 = GetAsyncKeyState('K'); 
    if ((0x80000000 & state) || 
        (0x80000000 & state1))
    {    
        printf("Kill Program"); 
        gRunning = FALSE;
    }
```

Comment: So do I just put a code like this at the top of my code? Also I'm a bit confused about how to properly use the syntax/what the parameters are of the function?

Comment: Google "GetAsyncKeyState MSDN", or click on the link I left above in the comment section of your question.

Comment: _So do I just put a code like this at the top of my code?_  Yes.  You define a function containing similar syntax to what I have provided for an _example_, ***But for your own purposes***, and ***call it*** from a within a loop running perhaps from your `main()` function.

Answer (score 0):

The terminal used in stdio is likely to be line buffered
(cooked).  If it is, checking for the escape key through scanf will 
not work.

SEE THESE URLS:

[Capture characters from standard input without waiting for enter to be pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pressed)

[scanf not reading input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289542/scanf-not-reading-input)

CURSES or NCURSES will detect the escape key (ASCII character 27), depending
on the terminal type.

This code can be used in WINDOWS to check for the ESCAPE
key.

```
    #include <conio.h> 
    #include <ctype.h>

    int ch;

    _cputs( "Type 'Y' when finished typing keys: " );
    do
    {
      ch = _getch();
      ch = toupper( ch );

          if (ch != 27) {
           _cputs( "CHARACTER: " );
           _putch( ch );
           _putch( '\r' );    // Carriage return
           _putch( '\n' );    // Line feed
      }

    } while( ch != 27 );
```